# Why doesn't backgroundColor=rgb(a,b,c) work?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Colors </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"));
        var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"));
        var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"));
        document.body.style.backgroundColor=rgb(a,b,c);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the background color change according to the RGB values? What have I done wrong??

Comment: Look at the error console.

Comment: what is the function rgb()? ;)

Comment: I just used like how it's used in HTML. :/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to use quotes:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mAVFs/1/).

Or:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [a,b,c].join(',') + ')';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mAVFs/).

*Unquoted* the JavaScript is passing the variables, as arguments, `a`,`b` and `c` to an undefined function called `rgb()`. As you're setting a CSS property you need to pass a string, hence the requirement of *quoting*.

Oh, and also you're using `parseInt()` which doesn't *require* a radix to be passed in, but it's better (and easier to avoid problems) if you do (the *radix* being the expected number-base):

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10) || 255,
    b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10) || 255,
    c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10) || 255;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mAVFs/2/) (In the demo I use `105` just so it's clear the default is being used if the <kbd>cancel</kbd> button is used).

And if someone hits 'cancel' on the prompt, you might want to supply a default argument to ensure that an actual colour-value is passed, since <kbd>cancel</kbd> otherwise, I think, evaluates to `false` (I'm assuming you'd prefer `255`, but obviously adjust to taste).

You could also, of course, simply define a function:

```
function rgb(r,g,b) {
    return 'rgb(' + [(r||0),(g||0),(b||0)].join(',') + ')';
}
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10),
      b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10),
      c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(a,b,c);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mAVFs/4/)

And this approach has the (perhaps specious) benefit of allowing a custom default value to be used:

```
function rgb(r,g,b, def) {
def = parseInt(def, 10) || 0;
    return 'rgb(' + [(r||def),(g||def),(b||def)].join(',') + ')';
}
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"), 10),
    b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"), 10),
    c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"), 10);
document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(a,b,c,40);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mAVFs/6/)

References:

- [`||` (logical `OR`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators).
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Can anyone explain that if rgb was used as a standard function in HTML and CSS, why doesnt JavaScript accept it as a standard function, why do i need to insert it in quotes?

Comment: Hello, what will be the procedure for variable that contain hex value, example: var hexValue = 0xFF0000; document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexValue; is this format acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around the value

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

rgb needs to be in quotation mark:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title> Colors </title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"));
      var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"));
      var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"));
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='rgb(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pduQ6/

Answer (score 0):

You have no function called `rgb(...)`

I think you meant to do:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the color needs to be a string:

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"),10);
var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"),10);
var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"),10);
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [a,b,c].join() + ")";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmaney/yRgwq/)