# Randomly colored circle

Tags: javascript, random, background-color

I am working on a little project which assigns a random color to this circle from all the possible colors.

I am trying to achieve this by assigning a random number to each RGB value. However, It doesn't seem to work this way. I also tried to setAttribute() way to assign it that way but also no luck. Please have a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Beginning JavaScript</title>
        <style>




        #circle{
            margin:auto;
            border:1px solid black;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
        }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="circle"></div>
<script>

var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
var value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
circle.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(value1,value2,value3)"
```

Comment: `circle.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + value1 + ","+value2+","+value3+")"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't backgroundColor=rgb(a,b,c) work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323082/why-doesnt-backgroundcolor-rgba-b-c-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the generated values into the style statement:

```
circle.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")";
```

Comment: Umm.. no semicolon there. I think you mean outside the quotes..?

Comment: Thanks. Is this because with my version it is not returning the value numbers but the string "value1" ?

Comment: @rgthree Yes you are right, it doesn't work with them before the quote. thanks